# Not able to see dynamic elements

Tags: appium, appium-android, inspector

[Appium app source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49OKz.png)

Is there any way to expand the app source hierarchy? Dev mobile team already added the identifier for these options but its not visible in app source.

Comment: Did you try switching to WebView context in the Appium Inspector?

Comment: @drunkencheetah No, Its hybrid application. resource-id and content-desc are already added and visible while inspecting through chrome inspector. But not visible through Appium Inspector

Comment: Exactly, because it is a hybrid application you have a Native context and a Webview context. The same way you are expected to switch contexts in your code, you should also be able to switch the contexts in the Appium Inspector. For my hybrid app the inspector automatically detects there is a Webview and presents a dropdown to switch between Native and Webview context. Check [this](https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/) out if you haven't